# EF Code First Object Context Cant find Stored Procedure at ExecuteFunction

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I am using EF 4.3 Code first with MySQL database. I am having problem executing stored procedure on the server. The code looks like as follows:

```
ExecuteFunction<SomeResultType>("StoredProcName",parameter1)
```

I am getting error The FunctionImport 'StoredProcName' could not be found in the container 'CodeFirstContainer'.

I have tried giving name as CodeFirstContainer.StoredProcName but no luck. Anyone have any idea about this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: UPDATE: For those who wants to know the way around ... http://www.lucbos.net/2012/03/calling-stored-procedure-with-entity.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you imported the stored procedure to your EDMX and created function import for it? `ExecuteFunction` is dependent on EDMX and function imports. If you are using code-first you cannot use it. You must use `ExecuteStoreQuery` / `ExecuteStoreCommand` on `ObjectContext` instance or `SqlQuery` / `ExecuteSqlCommand` on Database instance accessible through `DbContext` instance.

Comment: Nope. I am doing this via pure code. No edmx files involve in this. I already have pure entities (POCO) code working this way... so why not this? anyway like you said I cant use this if I am using code first..

Comment: In such case follow second part of my answer.

Comment: I have tried this but its throwing "Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored". Any idea?

Comment: I got it working now. Its a bug in Mysql .NET connector. I have upgraded to MySql .NET connector Version 6.5.4 and it works fine..